# How to update the QnA Maker Knowledge Bases in the orchestrator?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I created a bot with Orchestrator within the Sample from the BotBuilder-Samples and applied five knowledge Bases to it. I followed the steps and successfully deployed the bot.

My question now: When i want to updated content inside the knowledge Base (adding questions/answers for example), do i have to update the model somewhere and if so, how can i do it? Are there any PowerShell commands for this process?

In the past i used the Dispatch Sample and there is the `Dispatch refresh` command. Now i finaly had the time to upgrade to the orchestrator.

Link to the Sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-orchestrator

Comment: As mentioned below, refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/bf-orchestrator-cli?activeTab=readme#bf-orchestratorcreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the LUIS to Orchestrator migration document the following command we can use it for refresh Orchestrator snapshot with latest changes from your LUIS applications or QnAMaker knowledge bases.

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [Migration from LUIS Dispatch to Orchestrator](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/main/Orchestrator/docs/DispatchMigrationExample.md)

Comment: Welcome, @ddangler !!